# How to access a field in struct

Tags: lldb

I have the following code in my Xcode project:

```
- (BOOL)getIP;
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://httpbin.org/ip"]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
    [request setValue:@"TestValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Test"];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"getIP returns = %@", dict);

    return NO;
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in lldb using the "breakpoint set -b CFURLRequestSetHTTPHeaderFieldValue" command and trigger the getIP method, the code stops as expected.Then I intput the "po $x0
" lldb command and it prints "`<CFMutableURLRequest 0x1741bff00 [0x1a7808bb8]`> {url = http://httpbin.org/ip, cs = 0x0}".

What I want to know is: 1.how to access the url filed in struct CFMutableURLRequest; 2.how to get the definition of struct CFMutableURLRequest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `po` command shows you the result of the `description` message sent to the object.  There's no guarantee that the text printed by `description`is telling you about particular ivars in the object, it's just some free-form text that the class author can fill with whatever she best thinks describes the object.  The fact that it says "url =" doesn't mean there actually is an ivar called url.

You can use the `p` or `expr` commands to print the contents of the object (at least so far as that is available to the debugger.)  Since this is a pointer, you'll want to do:

```
(lldb) p *request
```

In this case, it looks like these are opaque objects - the debug information doesn't say how they are laid out.  So the debugger can't really help you look into the object directly.